# How to Recovering mysql database from data folder backup from uninstalled xamp to newly installed xamp

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have uninstalled the old XAMPP and deleted all of the content of `d:\xampp` folder and installed the new one. When I copy my backup folder (with the name of my database, containing all `.frm` and `.opt` files) to the `D:\xampp\mysql\data`, the database shows in the list in phpmyadmin but it has no tables and data. What I've done wrong?

tables are show in the database but while clicking on table its saying `file doesn't exist..`

Comment: have you copied the `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you restore old mysql\data\ to new installed xamp, your newly installed xamp version must be same as old xamp version.

Then only restore data will work. its worked on my xamp

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have not deleted the main file `phpmyadmin`
You should to search `phpmyadmin` in xampp file and delete `phpmyadmin` and past you're file in xampp again 
before you past `phpmyadmin` be sure you've delete it completely